# Вывести элемент по шансу

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
$el = [
   ['One', 33],
   ['Two', 33],
   ['Three', 33]
];
```

Первый параметр - имя, второй параметр - шанс.

Так вот, как вывести один элемент массива опираясь на шанс ?..

Если будет шанс 100 у какого то , выведет его, если у всех одинаковый - какой повезет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взять случайное число от нуля до суммы вероятностей, затем пройтись по массиву и найти элемент удовлетворяющий этому случайному числу.

```
 <?php
$arr = [
    "one" => 33,
    "two" => 33,
    "three" => 33,
];


function chance($arr)
{
    $sum = array_sum(array_values($arr));
    $rand = mt_rand(1, $sum);

    $cur = 0;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
        $cur += $item;
        if ($cur >= $rand) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

}

var_dump(chance($arr));
```

Comment: $rand = mt_rand(0, $sum); Лучше здесь установить от 1 значение, так как если будет стоять шанс 0 у элемента - есть вероятность того что выведет тот элемент шанс у которого равен 0
А вообще - возьму наверное Ваш вариант

Answer (score 1):

Создаете массив, в который заносите каждое имя столько раз, сколько цифр. Потом перемешиваете и берете первый элемент.

```
$arr = Array(
    "one"=>33,
    "two"=>33,
    "three"=>33,
);
$t = Array();
foreach($arr as $str=>$qty) {
    $t = array_merge($t, array_fill(0, $qty, $str));
}
//в этот момент в $t занесено 99 элементов: по 33 каждого.
shuffle($t);
echo $t[0];
```

Comment: Хороший способ конечно, но ресурсоёмкий

Comment: ну смотря что представляют из себя цифры. 33 - это проценты? или просто число 33, которое теоретически может быть и 333333?..

Comment: Ну по идее это должны быть проценты, но суть такая, что общее кол-во процентов будет не 100.
Элементов может быть около 30-ти, и у каждого свой шанс до 100.

Это получится 1 элемент шанс к примеру средний 50 - 30 элементов = 1500 элементов массива))

Но все - это тоже решение

Comment: В таком случае можно пересчитать массив: перевести шансы каждого элемента в проценты относительно общего кол-ва шансов, и решать далее как описано в ответе. Таким образом размер массива не будет больше 100 :)

Comment: У меня просто голова не так хорошо работает как у Вас, спасибо :)